# Catching exceptions raised in imported modules

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing a Python program which uses the pyserial module. The program is designed to read the output from an Arduino module. I can open a serial object with:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem641', 9600)
```

I can then read from it with:

```
line = ser.readline()
```

However, I want to be able to handle the exception that is thrown if I start the program without the Arduino module connected. The exception that is thrown is:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 292, in open
raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
```

If I try to catch this with a general `try/except` block in my main program, it isn't caught. I've tried importing the `SerialException` from `serialposix.py` but that doesn't work.

Do I need to get my hands dirty with threading or is there another way of dealing with this? When the exception is thrown, I'd like to call    `time.sleep(5)` and then just retry until the connection is available.

Comment: In your catch, try using - except serial.SerialException:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import [`serial.SerialException`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#exceptions) and catch that:

```
from serial import SerialException

try:
    line = ser.readline()
except SerialException:
    time.sleep(5)
```

The exception is a subclass of `IOError`, so you could use that too, but then you may be catching exceptions thrown for reasons other than the port not yet being available.