# How to catch an external exception in python?

Tags: python, import, try-catch, python-module

I'm writing a simple python script to move the mouse and i'm using pyautogui to do it. **The script must work both on Windows and Linux**. The problem is that [when i use linux Xlib raise Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/322). To solve this I used the try/catch clause to import pyautogui, but I don't know how to catch Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError.
As a workaround i'm using `except Exception:`, but it isn't very nice:

```py
import os
try:
    import pyautogui as pag
except Exception:
    os.system("xhost +SI:localuser:root")
    import pyautogui as pag
```

I've alredy saw:

> [Catching exceptions raised in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576675/catching-exceptions-raised-in-imported-modules)

but i can't import Xlib on Windows.

One solution seems to be:

```py
import os
if 'DISPLAY' in os.environ:
    import Xlib
    try:
        import  pyautogui as pag
    except Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError:
        os.system("xhost +SI:localuser:root")
        import  pyautogui as pag
else:
    import pyautogui as pag
```

but it's confusing, long and unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch a general exception and then simply check the specific type of it, without importing the external module:

```py
try:
    import 
except Exception as e:
    if e.__type__ == '':
        #do things...
    else:
        #do other things...
```

[Suggestion](https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-catch-external-exception/7712/2?u=mattep99) by [@tjollans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830621/tjollans)